# Receiver Sensitivity

Tags: noise, antenna, receiver, sensitivity

Receiver has noise figure 4 dB and ENBW 3.6 MHz. Used with antenna with noise temperature 200 K. Demodulator needs S/N of at least 13 dB.  What is the receiver sensitivity?  Give your answer in dBm, rounded to one decimal place.

Sensitivity = 10×log10(kTB)+NF+S⁄N

kTB = (1.38e-23)(210)(1) = 2.76e-21

Sensitivity = 10 x 10log10(2.76e-21) + 4 dB + 13 dB = -205.59 + 17 = -188.6 dBm

Is this correct?

Comment: the thermal noise floor at room temperature is -174dBm/Hz. Now, you have only ca half of that temperature, so that should be about 3dB less, i.e. -177 dBm/Hz. You got 3.6 MHz ~= 4 MHz ~= 66 dBHz of that. Your sensitivity is higher than (-177+66) dBm – that can't be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework without an attempt at a solution

Comment: @laptop2d wat.. his attempt is right there, three lines of equations

Comment: Sorry my bad, there is an attempt

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error:
Sensitivity = 10*log10(2.76e-21) + 4db + 13dB = -205.59 + 17 = -188.6 dB WATTS.

You have dbW; add +30dB and get -158.6 dBm